# Selecting elements from a list based on criterion in R

Tags: r, list, select

Let's say I have a list in R with some elements in it who have a property I'm particularly interested in.

How can I construct a list from the original list with only elements that have the property I'm looking for?

As an example, let's say `list` is defined as follows:

```
> list
[[1]]
[[1]]$Property
[1] TRUE
[[1]]$Name
[1] "Bob"

[[2]]
[[2]]$Property
[1] TRUE
[[2]]$Name
[1] "Alice"


[[3]]
[[3]]$Property
[1] FALSE
[[3]]$Name
[1] "Mike"
```

Suppose I wanted the list equivalent to `list[c(1,2)]`, the list of elements where `$Property` is `TRUE`. Is the best way to get this to loop over the list and save the indexes of those that match my constraint to a list of matching indexes and and then construct my list from the list of matching indexes?

Comment: `Filter(function(x) x$Property, list)` ? add your `dput` please

Comment: One options would be `x[sapply(x, "[[", "Property")]`